# Google Play Console - Existing Android Project get Key Store for signed Bundle

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-console, android-keystore

at my company I got the mission to improve our android application. This application was developed by an external company and now we want to continue the development in our own company.
We got the Android Project and the access data for the Google Play Console.
I'm not new to Android programming but never launched an App. That's why I have some troubles right now.

When I want to build a signed Bundle I need a Key Store.
If I understand it correctly, the Key Store is created once when you create a new App in Google Play Console. And with this Key Store all upcoming Updates are supposed to be signed too.

Is there a way to get the Key Store form Google Play Console or did the other company forget to send us the Key Store and we have to ask them for it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Ask the other company for keystore without it you cannot generate the signed bundle.apk

Comment: I think upload-key the external company is responsible for while app-signing-key Google is, and the latter none of your business.

Comment: Thank you to both of you. I got the key from the other company.